# Calling methods within an Objective C class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Coming from the Java world to the iPhone, I would like to see the following Java expressed in Objective C. For clarity's sake, I've kept the Obj-C class types.

```
NSString myData = "some stuff";
NSMutableArray myArray = parseDataIntoAnArray(myData);
...
private NSMutableArray parseDataIntoAnArray(NSString aString){
  NSMutableArray myArray = new NSMutableArray();
  // objects added here to myArray by manipulating aString
  return myArray;
}
```

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// All string literals require the "@" symbol at the beginning.
NSString *myData = @"some stuff";
NSMutableArray *myArray = [self parseDataIntoAnArray:myData];

-(NSMutableArray*)parseDataIntoAnArray:(NSString*)aString {
  NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

  return myArray;
}
```

Of course you would probably want to expose the method in the header file by including the method signature:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)parseDataIntoAnArray:(NSString*)aString;
```

Comment: Man, you're quick! Any tips on memory management here? Can you come by my house and help me gut out my project? :)

Comment: Haha. The best rule for memory management I have read is: "If you `alloc`, `copy`, or `new`, memory management is on you." Pretty much any other objects are `autorelease`d.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer: Don't forget retain.

Comment: @Alan: True, but I kind of figured that was understood.

Comment: You forgot to `*` your globals!

Comment: @Richard: Doh! I do believe it's time for bed =P

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * myData = @"some stuff";
// assumption is that parseDataInto... is a static method on your Foo class
NSMutableArray * myArray = [Foo parseDataIntoAnArray: myData];

+ (NSMutableArray *) parseDataIntoAnArray: (NSString*) aString
{
   NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array]
   // stuff here
   return myArray;
}
```

Note that your method (as you defined it) returns `NSString*`, and is assigning it to a `NSMutableArray*`, which are incompatible pointer types. My example above, switches the return type to `NSMutableArray*` which is what I think you mean to do.

Comment: Thanks, you obviously understood what I meant. Fixed the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first forget Java or any other programming languages.
Then you could read the documentation about Objective-C and the basic classes like NSString or others.
Just take a look at the actually working code, hope to help:

```
NSString *myData = @"some stuff";//string initializer
NSMutableArray *myArray = [self parseDataIntoAnArray:myData];//Object-C's message(just like methods or something)

//instance method, take a parameter named aString
- (NSMutableArray *)parseDataIntoAnArray:(NSString *)aString{
  NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];//array initializer

  [myArray addObject:aString];//another Message, add object to the array

  return myArray;//return the passed array, that's done.
}
```